# Python log file not rotating

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to use the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` from the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler) but it does not create a new log file and "rotate" the logging the new file. It just keeps logging to the same file.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


logging.basicConfig(
        handlers=[TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='runtime.log', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=7, encoding='utf-8')],
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s")
```

I just want it to log to a new file each calendar day and only keep 1 week's worth of log files.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I am running this script via cron job (mac) if it makes a difference.

Comment: That seems to work fine for me (I changed "days" to "minutes" for testing purposes).

Comment: Odd, i wonder what I could be doing wrong.....perhaps it's due do the fact that I running it via a cronjob ?

Comment: Maybe. I put it in a small script file and ran the script from command line, and it generated the correct number of files with correct time stamps.

Comment: When you say "running it via cronjob", does that mean you are restarting the script continuosly? Because that will of course reset the rotation timer. Whenever the script starts is time 0. and when a new day starts, while the script is running, from that moment on the logs of that script will be written to a rotated file.

Comment: @blues Oh shoot I think you're right. I am rerunning the script everytime. I'm essentially I'm pinging an API to check for something and logging the result to a file, which I'd like to rotate once a day. How can keep the logger "alive" while doing this?

Comment: You can't keep the logger alive without keeping the script alive. Why not just use a regular FileHandler, but use the current day as part of the filename? That's a nice and easy solution for short-lived scripts.

Comment: @blues Ah yes that's a smart solution. I wonder if I could make it roll/ autodelete though after a certain number of days.